# How can I change write and read endpoint to read-only in Aurora MySQL database in AWS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Now my database is using write & read endpoint, I want to configure it to read-only (or separate it into read-only and write-only), I'm very new to the whole database and AWS thing, can someone explain a bit and suggest a potential solution (I assume I don't need any configuration in AWS console, probably need to set the right read-only endpoint to my project config file?)

I've been reading some tutorials and documents regarding Aurora, but still no clue... any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume I don't need any configuration in AWS console, probably need
>   to set the right read-only endpoint to my project config file?

Correct. By default Aurora exposes both a read/write endpoint (which always goes to the current master node), and a reader endpoint which is load balanced across any read-replica nodes. You just need to change your application's connection settings to use the Aurora reader endpoint instead of the read/write endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This makes sense now, in terms of verifying the changes, is the metrics in monitoring (in AWS RDS) a better place or RDS performance insight?

Comment: Also I'm a bit confused about the purpose of changing it to read-only endpoints, is there any risk concern or it's for higher scalability?

Comment: To verify the changes I would look at the active connection count for each of the individual nodes, which is a CloudWatch metric.

Read-only endpoints are for scalability. You could always create a read-only database user account for security concerns. Load balancing requests across multiple read-replica servers is for scalability.

Comment: I push the changes to master, and used performace insight in RDS but seems it's still using the read/write points, did I miss anything? 'To verify the changes I would look at the active connection count for each of the individual nodes, which is a CloudWatch metric.' How can I find this metrics in AWS and why it's not using read-only points?

Comment: @Cecilia I can't answer a question like "why it's not using read-only points" without seeing your code. You can see the connection count for each individual node either in the AWS RDS console, or in the CloudWatch console.

Comment: @Cecilia, if you are using Nodejs ORM tools like sequelize, this will be handled automatically ref: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/read-replication.html